# PHP single instance - is this right?

Tags: php

My code is below. Does it look right?

```
<?php

class goMongoDB
{
private static $Instance;

public function goMongoDB() {

    if ( !isset(self::$Instance) )
    {
        self::$Instance = new MongoClient();
    }
}

public function isConnected()
{
    return self::$Instance->connected;
}
}

$MongoClient = new goMongoDB();



print $MongoClient->isConnected();


?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a singleton implementation.
Why?
You can instantiate it as many as you want.

How to go about it?

1 - Prevent direct instantitation

```
private function __construct(){}
```

2 - Provide an instantiation mechanism

```
static function getInstance(){
   if ( !isset(self::$Instance) ){
       self::$Instance = new MongoClient();
    }
   return self::$Instance;
}
```

Now you can get your object like this:

```
$obj = goMongoDB::getInstance();
```

Be warned though that singletons can make debugging a real pain so use with care.

Hope this helps